# android.intent.action.phone_state intent is unavailable in manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, telephony, telephonymanager

After adding these two permissions,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

When I try to create an intent filter for

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

Android studio doesn't show it is suggestion nor am I able to put it in manually.

Why am I not able to add it, was it deprecated or something? 
What is the replacement for that?

Comment: "nor am I able to put it in manually" -- why can you not type in that string? I don't see it in the code-completion drop-down list in Android Studio 1.3.2, so I filed [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187026) about that. But I can type in the string just fine.

Comment: Damn, so reliant on code completion. :3
Silly me. 
Thank you.